# Countdown Timer jn Java

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have to display the countdown timer on all registration pages for a web site (may 3 web pages for registration).
Let's say the time limit is 1 hour to complete the registration and the user took 10 mins to complete the fields on 1st web page, when he clicks next button to go to 2nd web page
the timer should show time from 49 mins.  How can I add this functionality to my existing code.

Here is my code for countdown timer.

```
public class CountdownTimer extends JLabel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long count;
    private long timerStart;
    private DateFormat dateFormat;

    javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, this);

    public CountdownTimer(int minutes, int seconds) {
        // suppose to show as in 30 MIN 30 SEC.
        super(" ", JLabel.CENTER);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
        count = cal.getTime().getTime();

        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");

        timer.start();
        timerStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()-timerStart;

        System.out.println(elapsedTime);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // suppose to countdown till 00 MIN 00 SEC
        setText(dateFormat.format(count));
        count -= 1000;

        if (dateFormat.format(count).equalsIgnoreCase("00:00")) {
            closeWindow();

        }
    }

    public void closeWindow() {

        System.exit(1);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setTitle("Countdown Timer");
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Registration closes in: ");
        panel.add(label);

        JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(jTextField);

        CountdownTimer c = new CountdownTimer(00, 60);

        frame.getContentPane().add(c);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should look up which technologies to use to create a WEB page and then we could provide help. Currently you are using Swing (not WEB)

Comment: Did you check what count is equal to when you start? Ill bet elapsedTime is always zero, but occasionally 1. Maybe you should check out [Duration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)

Comment: You should use dynamic web projects for Java web, not swing. If you do use swing, maybe look at the mvc pattern as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple I wouldn't even both with the api.

```
count = 60*minutes + seconds;
```

Then in the action listener.

```
count--;
if(count==0) exit(0);
```

If you wanted to be more robust about it. You should use the java.time api.

```
Instant finished = Instant.now().plus(minutes, ChronoUnit.MINUTES).plus(seconds, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
```

Now in your action listener you can check if you have reached the finish time.

```
if(Instant.now().isBefore(finished)){
    //do stuff
} else{
    //do your finished stuff.
}
```